# Python socket client works only for one iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, sockets

I am trying to implement sockets with python.the following code works well without the while loop..but with the while loop, for the second iteration , it gets stuck in s.sendall().could you please suggest how to fix this ?

```
def main():
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 11111                 
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((host, port))
    print "Connected to Server!"
    while True:
        print "Enter your Command:"
        command = raw_input()
        if(command):
            try:
                sock.sendall(repr(command))
            except socket.error:
                print "Socket Error Occured"

            data = sock.recv(1024)
            if data:
                print('Received', repr(data))
            else:
                print "No Data"
        else:
            os.system("clear")
    sock.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Hello

I don't have all the information I need to make this post as
informed as I'd like, however I can make some educate
d guesses and try my best to explain what I think is going wrong. Are you ready?? Lets get into it.

### So,

You start off by making a `tcp socket` and then connecting to a server hosted locally on port `11111`

```
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 11111                 
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((host, port))
```

next you enter a loop

```
    while True:
        #input command, request  eval
```

Here your goal is to take user input and send it to a server to `eval`. You do that with

```
        #get user input
        print "Enter your Command:"
        command = raw_input()

        #send command to server for eval
        sock.sendall(repr(command))

        #receive then print eval
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        print('Received', repr(data))
```

this works and sends commands as you'd expect, although sending `repr(command)` might not be what you want to send

```
command = "1+1"
eval(command) 
//2
eval(repr(command))
//'1+1'
```

### Now

Here is where I have to make some assumptions

Early on you **`connected` to a server**

```
    sock.connect((host, port))
```

I'm assuming that the server `accepts` your connection `evals` your `command` and sends the answer back. Something like

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind('localhost',11111)
sock.listen()

while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    command = conn.recv(1024)
    sock.sendall(eval(command))
```

If this is the case then your connection might fail because your eval server runs `eval` once and then `accepts` a new connection.
That means that your client can no longer send to, or recieve data from, the server

I hope this helps.